# Are there any permission settings to not allow checking the attributes(rwx) of a file?

Tags: permissions

For example, suppose a user doesn't have attribute-checking permission on the file `foo`. If the user calls `ls -l`, `foo` will not be shown (or maybe just the rwx attributes will not be shown).

Comment: I am not sure how helpful this is, but removing the 'executable' bit on a directory will stop you being able to check its contents. This could be used to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: The attributes of foo don't belong to foo, they are data in the directory that holds foo. Removing the executable bit for group/world will allow the names to show, but no stats- size, date, owner, attribs, etc. Removing the read bit for group/world will not even allow a file listing.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver there's the answer!

Comment: @CuriousKimchi:  Do you want the user to have access to the file without seeing the directory listing?  Do you mind if they see the file's attributes if they know the filename?  You should probably do some tests to see how it behaves as `chmod -x parent` will prevent any access since it blocks directory entry to be accessible, but `chmod -r parent` will only prevent a directory listing but allow specific directory entries to be retrieved, including the file's attributes.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver That's incorrect. attributes of a file are in the file's inode, which are independent of the directory that contains it (since you can have hard links from multiple directories). The execute attribute of the directory will prevent accessing any of the files through that directory, but if there are links from another directory you can get the attributes that way.

Comment: @Barmar You are correct. I stand corrected. The process still works, just have to verify lack of hard links to the files first.

Comment: Well then, I guess the question is not properly answered yet then. The perfect solution is if there is a method that prevents a user from checking the attributes of a file from that inode.

Comment: @CuriousKimchi:  What real problem are you trying to solve?  Even if you hid the permissions of a file, logical deduction would allow anyone who understands file permissions to deduct them even if you hid them.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I'm writing a FUSE program, and noticed you can also rewrite the `getattr` sys call. So I wanted to know the details regarding reading attributes. What do you mean by "logical deducation"?

Comment: @CuriousKimchi:  Even without any shell assistance, if `touch file` works, you have write access to it, if `cat file` works, you have read access and if `./file` doesn't give `Permission denied`, you have execute access.  Of course it doesn't show all the details but they're pretty much unimportant.  Trying to hide the permissions is an indication that you have a much bigger problem since giving access to your filesystem to someone that you don't want seeing the permissions means you are making really bad security decisions.

Comment: Actually, whatever way you show the file, the permission verifications remain essential to the regular operations, which makes them accessible one way or another.

Comment: Guess you are right